# sending index data to the server in for loop by using ajax (view engine is jade)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, pug

I'm trying to send my index data in the foreach loop to the server by using ajax but the server says it is 'undefined'. I hope that you might help me to solve the problem.

Here is my code

Jquery

```
$('#comment').each(function(index, element){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $.ajax(
            {method:'post',
             url:'/comment',
             data:{id:index}
            })
     })
})
```

Server

```
app.post('/comment', function(req,res){
   var id = req.body.id;
   console.log(id);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: when i use .click(function(){  alert(index) }, it works fine. the alert window shows me the index that i want to see. But ajax is not working..

Comment: `$('#comment').each` is red flag that you are repeating element ID's in page.

Comment: Are you using a body parser in node?

Comment: yes i'm using body parser

Comment: is it expecting json or form encoded data? `$.ajax` default is form encoded. Have you inspected whole body?

Comment: ahhh;; thank you charlietfl. weirdly that code is now working;